# Why adding a <script> tag at runtime doesn't load the javascript file? (with react.js)

Tags: javascript, loading, reactjs

I have this react.js script that adds the following code into the html

```
// returned by the render method
React.DOM.div({
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML:  {
        __html: '<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//myapp.disqus.com/embed.js"></script>'
    }
})
```

Now my html looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//myapp.disqus.com/embed.js"></script>
```

Which seems perfect but the problem is that it doesn't load the script. 
The script tag is inserted into the middle of the body, nested within some other div tags.

**What might be the problem?**
Thanks

Comment: The related page doesn't help me because I'm loading an external file. How would I do eval on it?

Comment: @user3446254, scroll down a little :-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/7054216/1074592

Comment: dirty solution for it in React.js `class XScript extends React.Component {
    static initScripts(el, url) {
        var script = document.createElement('script')
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        script.setAttribute('src', url);
        el.appendChild(script);
            
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        XScript.initScripts(React.findDOMNode(this.refs['it']), this.props.url);
    }
    
    render() {
        return <div ref="it" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<script type="text/javascript" src="'+this.props.url+'"></script>'}}></div>   
    }
}`

Comment: This should not be marked as a duplicate because it's specific to ReactJS - the other answers do not work in ReactJS

Comment: Hopefully this can be re-opened.

Answer (score 2):

Rendering the script tag to the page with react isn't the right solution - I coudln't get it to work with JSX, I assume the same applies here. Not sure why, but just add it the plain old javascript way:

```
    var script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "//myapp.disqus.com/embed.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Put that in the componentWillMount of your root component.

Answer (score 0):

I just added Disqus to my React app yesterday. I used the 'react-disqus-thread' module and had it up and running in no time.

Here it is on github: https://github.com/mzabriskie/react-disqus-thread

And npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-disqus-thread

The component takes the following props:

- shortname - This is 'myapp' in //myapp.disqus.com/embed.js
- identifier - a unique blogId that can identify your blog post if the url changes
- title
- url - if you do not provide this, the module will detect the url and provide it.

Answer (score -5):

Which browser you tested ? If you use async="true" in your script tag, it won't block. But that's only supported by a couple of browsers yet .

Comment: The problem is not to block or not, the problem is that is not even requesting the file at all.

Comment: did you get this resolved?  I'm having the same issue with reactjs