# How to embed a script in JSX in a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I have a script that loads an iframe that i have to embed on a particular route

My application is a universally rendered React app, and I included the script in my JSX code in the component registered to my route.

The iframe loads when I refresh the page on the route, but when I go from home -> other route, it wont load.

I've tried different workarounds using `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount`, but to no avail. Is there a way to force it to load when I visit the route from another route?

EDIT: i've checked and the script, is always there, but does not execute when not using server-side rendering

someone else had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558004/why-adding-a-script-tag-at-runtime-doesnt-load-the-javascript-file-with-rea#) and there was no sufficient solution short of including it at the root component of the app, which is overkill. so i have no idea what the solution is :(

```
class Component extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <script id="twine-script" src="//apps.twinesocial.com/embed?app=WCD&showNav=yes"></script>
        </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to inject a script on `componentWillMount` into the document head. You can argue that this isn't the most React way, but I think in this particular case it makes sense.

```js
const MyRouteComponent = React.createClass({

    componentWillMount() {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.onload = () => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true
            });
            console.log(TwineSDK); // TwineSDK should be defined now
        };
        script.src = '//apps.twinesocial.com/embed?app=WCD&showNav=yes';
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    },

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            isLoaded: false
        }
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            {
                this.state.isLoaded ? <div>Loaded!</div> : <div>Loading...</div>
            }
            </div>
        );
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you! is there a way to get this script to execute? not only do i have to embed it, but it has to run on page load as well

Comment: @KimLee In case people visit this page later, you could always functions to wrap logic codes